# Why would some python objects "refuse" to go into a standard python list?

Tags: python, list

I'm working with a library and am working primarilly with a specific object in that library of lets say type X. This library provides a custom container like object, XList, that appears to behave mostly like a list.

It appears that when I do the following:

```
xl = makeXList(...)
l = []
for x in xl:
    print repr(x)
    l.append(x)
```

The resulting "l" is an empty list. I nevertheless see the x's fly by the std out -- so I know they are truly being iterator over. I repeat the same, but change x to [1,2,3] and l is now [1,2,3]. What gives?

Is there some way that instances of type X could be refusing to go into a normal python list? **Or is there a benign, newbish reason this might not be working like I expect?** What is the mechanism for doing this? Is this a common intentional thing for python library writers to do? The documentation for this library appears sparse, and some of the examples appears to show a normal python list of Xs which I find rather odd.

---

**what the problem was**

The library in question is scapy. scapy seems to be encountering a malformed packet and refusing to convert from PacketList-> python list when reading a malformed packet from a pcap when using rdpcap. The above code works fine when scapy is working with non-malformed packets.

Comment: Post some more code. You're being way too general. Maybe post some interpreter inputs and outputs as well?

Comment: Something we can test would be helpful...

Comment: Are you sure `xl` isn't empty?

Comment: Are you certain the `xl` from makeXList is actually populated and enumerable? Add a print statement inside the loop just to verify you're not chasing a phantom

Comment: @JoelCornett I'll try to recreate the example. More specifically I'm using scapy and getting PacketLists. I'm assuming I'm being a complete newb and there's something deeper about python I'm just not seeing

Comment: Can you check the source to your XList class? Does it have a custom __iter__ function?

Comment: @DougT.: it just occurred to me that I never said what the newbie mistake might actually be for someone who didn't already know it.  If xl isn't a Python list but is an iterator, then you can probably only loop over the elements **once**.  So if you did anything to xl before the above loop that you didn't mention, the elements aren't there anymore in your for loop.

Comment: Please see my udpate, it appears to be something with how scapy is behaving. Its not actually a newb misunderstanding of something in python like I thought (which is why I was asking in a generic fashion). Thanks for the help everyone.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you're actually getting entries in your for-in loop?  Perhaps the iterator for xl isn't working properly, so you aren't actually getting any elements back.